# Convert an american style minute string into integer value

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

I got an american format string showing seconds of an elapsed event, like `4,942.221s`. How would be the most pythonic way to convert this into an integer without parsing and removing comma. I want to get the plain seconds, which in this case would be `4942`, ms can be truncated.

Comment: What do you mean "without removing the comma?"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In Germany you don't split up large numbers by a comma, so you would not say something like 4,723,192.123 but 4723182,123.

Comment: I am aware of differences in formatting numbers in different locales. I see from your comment in another answer that you are probably searching for the `locale` library functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use float first and then convert to int as below

```
>>>a= '4,942.221s'
>>>int(float(a.replace(',', '').replace('s','')))
>>>4942
```

Comment: This is a solution right now for me, right now. Thanks for that. What I was thinking about, was some kind of general approach using number format depending on timezone or so. I'm not aware yet of such mechanisms in python and would like to learn about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using the [`locale`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/locale.html) library, which

> allows programmers to deal with certain cultural issues in an
>   application, without requiring the programmer to know all the
>   specifics of each country where the software is executed.

Normally, this would be used to deal with certain issues of formatting strings and such while being agnostic about the locale, however, if your system supports the American English locality settings, then you could do the following, which is a bit hackey, to solve your problem:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US.UTF-8')
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> locale.atoi('123,456,789')
123456789
>>> locale.atof('123,456.787')
123456.787
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/juan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 595, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
>>> american_string = '4,942.221s'
>>> int(locale.atof(american_string[:-1]))
4942
```

You might have to figure out the exact argument to pass to the second parameter of the `setlocale` function, because it will depend on your system. For example, note the error when I tried to set the German locale, which isn't currently supported on my system. In case you are on Ubuntu, the following should work: `sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base`